# Is there any if statment in awk to compare a word greped from a file?

Tags: awk

I am new to any programming and shell scripting.

I am trying to make a if condition in shell script.
I am used of some computed codes for density functional theory (say Quantum espresso).

I want to make the program automatic via a shell script.

My code produce case.data which contains at the end stop (at $2 or we can say at second column).
For example below script should print stop

```
cat case.data | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

so if I get stop from above script then then if statement should not produce anything and the rest file should be executed. If I do not get stop from then above script then executable commands in my file should not be executed and a text file containing exit should be executed so that it terminates my job.

What I tried is:

```
#!bin/bash
#  Here I have my other commands that will give us case.data and below is my if statement.
STOP=$(cat $case.dayfile | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
if [$STOP =="stop"]
then
         echo "nil"
 else

    echo "exit" > exit
   chmod u+x exit
   ./exit
fi
#  here after  I have other executable that will be executed depending on above if statement
```

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Hii Cyrus, I tried there but I could not understood it.

Comment: Please consider $case.dayfile as $case.data

Comment: Note that you need spaces around the command name `[` and its last argument needs to be `]`, and you need spaces around operators, so you should have written `if [ "$STOP" = "stop" ]` — you cannot be sloppy with white space in shell scripts!

Comment: Also, `exit` is a shell built-in.  Using `./exit` seems to imply you have a program or script called `exit` in your current directory.  Most of the time, that'll be ignored by the shell, except when you use it with a path component, but it will confuse people reading your script. (It confuses me; I'm extremely puzzled and/or curious about what it contains.)  Don't use shell keywords or built-in command names as the names of scripts or programs.

Comment: Wrt [your shellcheck comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985569/is-there-any-if-statment-in-awk-to-compare-a-word-greped-from-a-file#comment98620447_55985569) `I tried there but I could not understood it.` - When you paste your code into shellcheck the first error message is a pointer to the `[` in `[$STOP =="stop"]` saying exactly `You need a space after the [ and before the ].`. What is difficult to understand about that?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the script `./exit` contains the command `exit`. He creates that script with the `echo "exit" > exit` 2 lines above where he calls it. "why?" is the big question!

Comment: @EdMorton: Hmmm; yes — I didn't see that it created the script `./exit`.  It would make more sense if the code used `. ./exit` — but it is still not really clear why not write just `exit` and not create the file (which should be cleaned up on exit — `trap`), and so on.  Weird!  So, the big question is, indeed, **why create and use `./exit`?***

Comment: You want to ensure the case.data is complete before you process it? If the file gets very large it’s not a good idea to read it completely to the end just to find a stop word. If you cannot change they way completeness is signaled (for example rename the file only on success) then it would be probably better to use `dd` to only read the last block of the file.

Comment: Hii Jonathan Leffler and Ed Morton, thanks for asking the clarification. As I am new to this shell scripting so I did not recall the shell built in exit. I will take care of this any shell built-ins. I also used the space before command name and operator but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole script should be changed to just this assuming you really do want to print "nil" in the success case for some reason:

```
awk '{val=$2} END{if (val=="stop") print "nil"; else exit 1}' "${case}.data" || exit
```

and this otherwise:

```
awk '{val=$2} END{exit (val=="stop" ? 0 : 1)}' "${case}.data" || exit
```

I used a ternary in that last script instead of just `exit (val!="stop")` or similar for clarity given the opposite values of `true` in a condition and `success` in an exit status.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ed Marton, your solution worked for me perfectly using cat $case.dayfile | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' > stop.dat and then awk '{val=$0} END{if (val=="stop") print "nil"; else exit 1}' "stop.date" || exit.

Comment: You misunderstand. You don't need to do `cat $case.dayfile | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' > stop.dat` first - **ALL** you need is the script I posted (updated now to use $2 instead of $0 in case that was what was throwing you).

Comment: Your script is perfect. I have voted up for this but I haven't earned the appropriate voting privilege so it will not show here. Anyway, my vote is recorded.

Comment: Done, thanks for your valuable response. Regards, Kailash

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
if awk 'END{if($2!="stop")exit 1}' case.data
then 
    echo execute commands here
fi
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. James Brown for your reply. I tried the solution provided by Ed Marton and it worked for me. Your is also similar to Ed Marton's reply so I assume it will also work. Thanks for giving your valuable time. Regards, Kialash